# Boosting 18 V drill battery to 60 V to power LED lights, problems with voltage stability

Tags: power-supply, batteries, boost, lipo, buck-boost

I have a bunch of Dewalt 18 V batteries and 2 LED shop lights that I converted to DC, specifically 60 V, 1.5 amps per strip. I have had mixed luck and I am looking for a better approach.

I have no problem building boards, but I was trying to take a short cut and I grabbed one of these:  [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07L6F6S6S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L6F6S6S)
to boost 18 V to 60 V. This did work, but as the batteries drain the voltage went down and the boost went down proportionally, so the light did not last a long time. I added a 15 V regulator, but that got super hot.

Does anyone have an opinion on what is the right way to do this? I need to make a constant voltage power supply that takes 12-18 V and boosts to 60 V, which does not fluctuate as the battery drains.

Comment: These modules often have misleading specs. In my experience the '60V' spec is for higher input voltages- you may not be able to get a reliable 60V with an 18V input.

Comment: Yep, I am trying to move away from a module like this Im just trying to figure out if I need to regulator then boost the voltage to get it stable or if there is another approach to take

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your batteries may be too small.

I use modules that look very much like (probably identical) for my LED yard lights.  However, my lights must be smaller than yours - mine are 38V @ 1.7 Amps.  I removed the original power supply and use these modules instead.

The smallest battery I use is Dewalt Flex-Volt batteries - I have both 6Ah & 9Ah at 20 Volts.  Do note that Dewalt plays a little loose with their battery voltage ratings - most people would call these 18V packs rather than the 20V rating that Dewalt uses.

My battery packs are 3P5S with either 2AH cells (6Ah) or 3Ah cells (9Ah).    These packs can be switched into 60V mode by means of a mechanical switch contained in the battery pack but I'm using them in 20V mode.

My portable lights work extremely well with those power supplies.  Do note that I am using the power supplies in Constant Current mode.  The open-circuit voltage is set to be a couple of volts higher than the maximum voltage that the LED lamps will ever require and the current is set to the proper value.

I've also used those modules to power 4' LED strip lights (fluorescent bulb replacement).  I'm using one module per lamp, directly feeding the LED array inside the tube.  In other words, I'm not using the internal power supply within the tube.  Also great performance using the Dewalt battery packs.

Comment: so this is for 4' replacement work lights, there are 2 leds strips per lamp and they definitively need 60v to run. I had been trying to run 2 lamps per battery, so 4 strips in total. I can probably just switch the design and run a single lamp per module and see how that works.

Comment: I pulled out the regulator, adjusted the voltage a little high and set the current, worked great for 20 min, I did the math batteries lasted exactly as long as they should have. So you are right, batteries are just too small.